# Uber access issue to the menu fetch API

Tags: uber-api

We got an access token using the API: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token and it is working fine for our restaurant app.
but when fetching the menu it is given the below error:

API: [https://api.uber.com/v2/eats/stores/{store_id}/menus](https://api.uber.com/v2/eats/stores/%7Bstore_id%7D/menus)
Error : “Client error: `GET https://api.uber.com/v2/eats/stores/{store_id}/menus` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:\n{\“code\“:\“unauthorized\“,\“message\“:\“unauthorized\“}\n”

Could you please advise on this?

Comment: I think token is incorrect or token has no privileges to access menu api.

Comment: Token has access to all scopes

Comment: Is it previously working fine? or is it the first time integration?

Comment: it was working fine with a test account with test restaurant. this is the first production integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to store_id was not configured. call uber support and fixed it